# Parsing v-html content in Vue

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, headless

I have a page where I'm currently getting a html string using Wordpress' REST api. I'd love to be able to create a Navbar component that parses the html, looks at all of the heading tags and generates anchor links for each header. Is it possible to search v-html using Vue to dynamically create this component?

This is the axios call to get the wordpress data. And the end point i'm getting returns 'content' from a Post page - which is a HTML string that I'm using v-html to render.

```
data() {
    return {
        loading: true,
        baseUrl: 'https://sitename.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/'
    }
},

methods: {
    fetchData() {
        axios.get(`${this.baseUrl}${this.$route.params.id}/`)
            .then((resp) => {
                const data = resp.data; //this is the wp data
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: But REST api like in Wordpress should return for ex. Json data. So why there is v-html anyway? Just some "a" or <route-link> tags with v-for and that's it.

Comment: @chojnicki So the REST api returns back a html string for content that's generated via the Wordpress WSYIWYG, which is where i'm having most difficulty - since I can't change how that's structured. This is to prototype a split test for a current site - so they don't want me to edit the content on the site, just redesign it.

Comment: did you find a good way to do this?

Comment: @v3nt It's been a long time, so I'm afraid I can't remember. The way I'd probably do this now is to run a computed method that finds all <a> tags and adds them to an array, and adds anchor tags; then I'd use this data to create a DOM element at the top of the page that iterates through the array and references the newly created anchors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know You are not able to import head tag in the v-html, hence, you can render components as a static page with _slug in vue js.

Comment: This should (maybe) be a comment and not an answer